# video lectures on topological K-theory?

Tags: k-theory

I am trying to follow Karoubi's book on Topological K-theory and it would be great motivation if I had any video lectures to watch. Do you have any in mind? I would also appreciate any problem sets from a course on topological K-theory to guide my studying of Karoubi.

Answer (score 0):

I lately found [these lecture](http://online.itp.ucsb.edu/online/ktheory/)s on Topological K-Theory that I started watching them myself. I am not sure how well they match with Karoubi but the first half seems to introduce the basic concepts of K-theory. The second half is more focused on applications to D-branes (It more of a physics thing and maybe less interesting for you?). They don't have video recordings, but a good set of handwritten notes and audio recordings.

Comment: I have been looking at Atiyah's book 'K-Theory', if you happen to know any other (introductory) notes on the topic (preferably for someone with more of a mathematical physics background) I would love to hear it.